# Why is the Image file a PE executable

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, make, images, binary

I've been trying to compile a linux kernel on my own machine with the source linux-6.0-rc5, which is the latest. Everything goes well yet something haunts me. When I get the `Image` file under arch/riscv/boot and use a `file` command to view it, I found it looks like:

```
Image: MS-DOS executable PE32+ executable (EFI application) RISC-V 64-bit (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

Yet in my mind it should be of `data` type since `objcopy -O binary -S` should have trunked all other informations.

I've `file`d the `vmlinux` file and get

```
vmlinux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, UCB RISC-V, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=432bf8175b2c7de8404f27f5f395fdb20479f263, with debug_info, not stripped
```

when I retry with a newly build C program with the same type, using the `objcopy` as the one that have been done to `vmlinux`, I get the correct `data` type.

Manually `objcopy`ing `vmlinux` is getting the same result as PE Executable, so it's impossible that `make` system has done extra changes.

The thing done with the `vmlinux` to get `Image` is

```
riscv64-linux-gnu-objcopy -O binary -R .note -R .note.gnu.build-id -R .comment -S vmlinux arch/linux/boot/Image
```

as we can see with `--just-print` options on `make`.

I'm wondering if I've misread the meaning of the line `objcopy` or the result of `file` command.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the boot image is a UEFI executable whose format is [Portable Executable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI) (a.k.a Windows exe).